# Probability Indicator Random Variable for CLRS Random-Search

Tags: probability, analysis, random-variables

The pseudocode below is to do a random search for an index $i$ s.t A[$i$] = x

```
Initialize an array P of size n containing all zeros
Initialize integers c and i to 0
while c != n do
  i = RI(A)
  if A[i] == x then
    return i
  end if
  if P[i] == 0 then
    P[i] = 1
    c = c + 1
  end if
end while
return A does not contain x
```

The problem statement in CLRS is "**Assume there is exactly one i such that A[i] = x. What is the expected number of
checks of A[i] = x Random-Search performs before terminates.**"

The solution for the expected value is $E[N]$ = $\sum_{i \geq 1}$ $i$ $P(X_i)$, where $X_i$ = {index $i$ is picked at iteration i}

I understand how $P(X_i)$ = $(\frac{n-1}{n})^{i-1} \frac{1}{n}$ in the expected value summation, however I don't understand putting why we need the $i$ in  $i$*$P(X_i)$?

From some examples I saw in the textbook, the indicator random variable value was  just
$I(X) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if an event occurs} \\ 0 &\text{if an event does not occur}\end{cases}$

So I got $E[N]$ = $\sum_{i \geq 1}$ $I(X_i)$ $P(X_i)$.

In the case of this problem why is the value of $I(X_i)$ = $i$ in  $E[N]$ = $\sum_{i \geq 1}$ $i$ $P(X_i)$?

I guess I am just confused on what values to use for the random variable. When is it appropriate to use 0 or 1 vs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...,n for the values of a random variable?

Comment: Do you know the/a definition of expected value of a random variable?

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph yes, it's E(X) = Σ x P(X = x), but I'm just confused why the value of x is i in this case, and not 1 since I was glancing over examples in the textbook. I guess I'm just not sure what values to pick for a random variable like when to use 0 or 1, or 1,2, 3, ..., n